# Agregar modal a Rails y devise

Tags: ajax, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

Saludos gente, como puedo agregar un modal a la parte de formulario de login en rails 4?

Tengo devise instalado y necesito que se despliegue un modal cuando el usuario haga click en la opción login del sitio

Comment: Hola Felipe, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Te recomiendo que conozcas la comunidad haciendo el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que revises el tema [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A continuación, reformula tu pregunta y asegúrate esta vez de incluir el código relevante.